# I keep getting connection timeout error trying to connect to mysql database using NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to connect to an external mysql database from nodejs using `util.pomisify`. Below is my code

```
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var async = require('async');
var util = require('util');
var dbCon = mysql.createPool({
    host : '169.255.58.96',
    user : 'username',
    password : 'password',
    database : 'database',
    acquireTimeout : 1000000,
    connectTimeout : 1000000,
    waitForConnections : true,
    queueLimit : 0
});
var query = util.promisify(dbCon.query).bind(dbCon);
```

But I get time out error. Then I try to connect to the database directly without using `util.promisify`

```
var mysqliQuery = dbCon.getConnection((err, connected) => {
    console.log('Connecting to Database');
    if(!err)
        console.log('Database Connected');
    else
        console.log(err.code);
});
```

But I still get the **ERTIMEDOUT** message... Please can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you connect to the database using the same credentials with a command line utility like `mysql` or `mycli`?

Comment: @robertklep... Yes I can. I'm in fact I'm using the same credentials to connect to the database using `PHP` `MySQL`

Comment: I was using `localhost` as the **host**, but then I had to change it to the IP address to confirm it's working, and for sure, it worked

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as a connection creation

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host : '169.255.58.96',
    user : 'username',
    password : 'password',
    database : 'database',
    acquireTimeout : 1000000,
    connectTimeout : 1000000,
    waitForConnections : true,
    queueLimit : 0
});
```

and to make sure if you are connected or not use this:

```
db.connect((error)=>{
    if (error){
        console.log(error)
    } else {
        console.log("Connected..")
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you test this code before writing because this is a similar code to mine. It makes no difference